# How to pass dictionary values from a django query, as a filter value in another query?

Tags: django, django-queryset

query 1:

```
nearestzips = PostalCode.objects.distance(PostalCode.objects.get(code='user.zipcode').location).order_by('distance')[:9]
```

print nearestzips

```
>>>[<PostalCode=97202>, <PostalCode=97201>, <PostalCode=97215>, <PostalCode=97239>, <PostalCode=97214>]
```

query 2:

```
latest_entries = Entry.objects.filter(zipcode__in=nearestzips.values())
```

print latest_entries

```
>>>TypeError: Cannot use a multi-field GeoValuesQuerySet as a filter value.
```

I am trying to take 'nearestzips' which contains 5 postal codes, and query entries that match those postal codes, but I am getting the error above.  any advice?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than use .values(), use a .values_list() with whatever field you want to match on:

```
latest_entries = Entry.objects.filter(zipcode__in=nearestzips.values_list('myField', flat=True))
```

Comment: I will try this, but do you think this is the cause of my error?

Comment: I believe this answer should work, if not, wrapt the `values_list` in a `list()` call to turn it into a real python array/list.

Comment: Yes, this is the cause of your error. There shouldn't be a reason to wrap the `values_list` into `list()` when `flat=True` is passed in, because this will return a standard list, not a queryset.

Comment: would 'myField' just be 'PostalCode' ?

Comment: nevermind, it's 'code', but i get another error. programmingerror: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "cities_postalcode" HINT perhaps you meant to reference the table alias"u0"

Comment: I'd need to see your models to understand what you're trying to access here. It should be whatever `ModelField` on `PostalCode` that you want to filter by. It would also help to see the `Entry` model since that presumably has a foreign key to `PostalCode`. Please update the original question with the code for those models.